# Using UPPER() to convert range in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'd like to use SUMIF in one column if the value in another column is "Y", and I'd like to combine this with the UPPER() function for the column containing the "Y"s.  Here's what I tried"  `=SUMIF(UPPER(E2:E18), "Y", C2:C18)` but I get an error.  It works if I remove the UPPER() function.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UPPER()` function by default only works on a single value. If you supply a range/array to it, the function will use the first cell in the range or the first value of the array. The result is always a string, though.

The `SUMIF()` function expects a range as its first argument. Since the result of the `UPPER()` function is a string, Excel throws an error.

Now, of course, the comparison in the `SUMIF()` function is case insensitive, so this formula

```dart
=SUMIF(E2:E18, "Y", C2:C18)
```

works correctly to detect both `y` and `Y`.

If for some reason you *really* want to use `UPPER(),` this is the correctly working equivalent formula to what you would expect `=SUMIF(UPPER(E2:E18), "Y", C2:C18)` to do:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((UPPER(E2:E18)="Y")*(C2:C18))
```

The reason why `UPPER()` works in this case is that `SUMPRODUCT()` expects its arguments to be arrays, so Excel returns an array of strings from it.